# Grammar using "because of" in future tense

Tags: word-choice

Is it proper to say, "he will be absent because of sickness?"

It sounds strange to me and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Using "because" this way is perfectly proper, it's what follows that seem odd to me. I would prefer "because he's sick." Using "sickness" here makes it sound like a name. Or consider using "due to" instead of "because".

Comment: The example sentence that came to me, somewhat amusingly, is "He will be absent because of a prior commitment." :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the strangeness has nothing to do with tense but is present because of the formulation

> because of sickness

More natural alternatives:

> due to sickness
>
> because he's sick